# How to execute a script, from another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a machine state using the animator, because it looks easier to me.

However i'm not being able to execute one of my states in the animator. Hope you guys can help.

```
private flagmove Script;  

override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo animatorStateInfo, int layerIndex) 
{



}       


override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo animatorStateInfo, int layerIndex) 
{
    Script = GameObject.Find("MANAGER").GetComponent<flagmove>();
    Script();
    //Debug.Log("called code");

}

override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo animatorStateInfo, int layerIndex) 
{



}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "execute a script"? Usually you would just call `Script.MethodName();` here. Also just a note on standard C# code style: typically, class names are "PascalCase" like `FlagMove` and variable names are "camelCase" like `script`, so it's a smidge confusing that you have a class called `flagmove` and a variable called `Script`

Comment: The execute i mean by making the script active. But thanks to you i have realized the way i was making this wouldn't work, because two states are in one script.

Comment: `Script = GameObject.Find...;` `Script.enabled =  true;`

Comment: This still helps thanks.